# how to give GLOBAL PRIVILEGES in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need limited Global permission like Select Execute and grant privileges  to one user.

how can i give, can any one help me.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To provide All privileges to an user from a specific server your Grant commands can be like the one below.

```
     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO 'user'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <password>;
     FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

To provide select and execute grants to your user,

```
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON database_name TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Don't forget to `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after executing the grants.

Comment: Grant takes effect immediately, therefore FLUSH PRIVILEGES is not necessary. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privilege-changes.html

Comment: The answer from @ngin is syntactically the correct answer. This accepted answer had `database_name`. That would not be a global privilege, but a database level privilege.

Comment: Not correct, dbname should not be mentionned

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is not correct. And I don't have the appropriate reputation to comment on it so womp.

The question being asked is how to grant global privileges. Global privileges are marked by a `*.*` after the `ON`

So, to fix the accepted answer's question

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'hostname';
```

or

```
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON *.* TO 'user'@'hostname';
```

Comment: Very good eye (+1). Your answer should be the accepted answer. By the way, welcome to the DBA StackExchange.

Comment: thta is so not correct in mysql 5.5 to 5.7 this is valid, so your informatipon is not valid in those releases